# Python3 pull emails past a certain date using MAPI

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to create a script that pulls emails from a certain folder after a certain date. I have a text document, dateLastRan.txt in which the date the last time this script was ran is stored. The data in there will be akin to 2018-09-18.

I grab the date from the document and I grab the date of the messages. I was hoping to only output emails that were past the dateLastRan, but my comparison is complaining. And yeah, I am new to python. Thanks for any advice!

```
  if(msgDate>dateLastRan):  
TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.date() > str()
```

I respect the error, but how to get around it? Relevant code below:

```
    import win32com.client
    import datetime
    import re

    badUrl = []

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    your_folder = namespace.Folders.Item(1)

    folder = 'ANY' #change this entry to match a folder found within Inbox

    inbox = your_folder.Folders['Inbox'].Folders[folder]    


    dateLastRan = '1991-01-01' #used to initialize datelastran
    todaysDate = (datetime.date.today())    #used to determine where to pick back up
    startDate = '1991-01-01'#used to initialize startDate

   #Grab Last Date Ran from file
    try:
        with open('lastDateRan.txt', 'r') as infile:
            for date in infile:
                dateLastRan = date
    except Exception as err:
        print ("lastDateRan.txt not found", '\n')

    print("Date Last Ran = ", dateLastRan, '\n')


    all_messages = inbox.Items   


    print("Pulling URLs from folder:",folder,'\n')

    for message in all_messages:
            msgDate = message.senton.date() #get date of message
            print("msg date: ", msgDate)
            print("datelastran: ",dateLastRan)
            if(msgDate>dateLastRan): #<<<<<Comparison here
                print("woot")
                #do stuff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was `todaysDate.replace('-','')` to remove the dashes and `int(todaysDate)` to cast the number. For the date I grabbed from file I had to use `dateLastRan = re.sub('-', '', dateLastRan)` because .replace was not useable and then followed that with `int(dateLastRan)`. I could then compare properly and only touch emails after the date of the lastDate. 
This doesn't take into account time of day, but it's working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Date types and string types cannot be compared.  dateLastRan = '1991-01-01' is a String types. So you need to convert to datetime Type.

Please refer to this code :

```
begin = datetime.date(2018, 9, 17)  #year, month, day
end = datetime.date(2018, 9, 18)
if(begin > end):
  print("False")
else:
  print("True")
```

Comment: The problem I come across is getting the dates from the email and working with them. I am not looking to input dates manually.

Comment: Sorry for my bad sample. I known your request. I just told you the issue reason and give your test sample. You can change the code "dateLastRan = '1991-01-01'" to dateLastRan = datetime.date(1991, 1, 1) in your full code.